# Passing a pointer of inaccessible private base type to the derived class method

Tags: c++

This code example would describe the language feature I find non-intuitive.

```
class A {
public:
  A() {}
};

class B: private A
{
public:
  B() {}
};

class C: public B
{
public:
  C() {}
  void ProcessA(A* a) {
  }
};

int main() {
  C c;
}
```

Compilation of this code with Apple LLVM version 4.2 on Mac produces an

```
test.cc:16: error: ‘class A’ is inaccessible
test.cc:16: error: within this context
```

Replacing `void ProcessA(A* a)` with `void ProcessA(::A* a)` would make it build but I don't understand why should I use absolute class name here.
Is it a language feature that is there to avoid certain kind of errors or is it just a dark C++ grammar corner like requirement to put space between angle brackets (`> >`) in templates parametrized with other templates.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Human talk

I 'll start by describing what happens here -- forgive me if you already know this, but it creates necessary context for the follow-up.

The compiler resolves the unqualified `A` to `::C::A` (the result will be the same if you make the change at source level yourself). Since `::C::A` is inaccessible an error message is emitted.

You are proposing that the compiler should detect that `::C::A` is inaccessible and the reference to `A` should then be considered a reference to `::A` as a fallback. However, `::C::A` and `::A` may easily be two *entirely different things*.

Automatically guessing what should be done here is not only prone to introducing bugs and/or hair-pulling¹, but also completely contrary to the spirit of C++.

### Standardese

Confirmation that this behavior is conformant and by-design, directly from the C++11 standard.

§9/2 says:

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared
>   immediately after the *class-name* is seen. The *class-name* is also
>   inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the
>   *injected-class-name*.

This means that inside the scope of class `C`, `A` is an *injected-class-name*.

§3.4/3 states that the *injected-class-name* is a candidate for name lookups:

> The injected-class-name of a class is also considered to be a member
>   of that class for the purposes of name hiding and lookup.

§3.4/1 clarifies that the inaccessibility of the base `A` does not prevent the *injected-class-name* `A` from being considered:

> The access rules are considered only once name lookup and function
>   overload resolution (if applicable) have succeeded.

§11.1/5 gives a direct explanation of the *exact* situation under discussion:

> [Note: In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will find
>   the *injected-class-name* instead of the name of the base class in the
>   scope in which it was declared. The *injected-class-name* might be less
>   accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it
>   was declared. —end note ]

The standard also gives this example, which is equivalent to yours:

```
class A { };
class B : private A { };
class C : public B {
    A *p;   // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
    ::A *q; // OK
};
```

---

¹ Imagine what happens if `A` is initially a `public` base, then later becomes `private` during a refactoring. Also imagine that `::A` and `::C::A` are unrelated. You would expect that a call like `a->foo()` (which used to work) would fail because `foo` is no longer accessible, but instead of this the type of `a` has changed behind your back and you now get a "there is no method `foo`" error. Huh?!? And that's of course far from the worst that could happen.

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but I'm still in doubt: I agree that compiler should not decide on itself which `class A` to use if there are more than one accessible (from different namespaces, right?). But I don't understand why when there is only _one_ A such inheritance makes it's public interface inaccessible. It's a completely different object and the interface is public. Passing `&c` (from `main`) or `this` (from some other `C` member function) into `ProcessA` would naturally fail because of inaccessible conversion anyway.

Comment: @IgorKozyrenko: I updated the answer with citations from the standard, which completely covers the *what* happens here (TL;DR: conformant behavior). As to the *why*: I cannot answer this definitively, but making a special exception for this particular case does not sound like a good idea when there is such an easy and familiar workaround (fully qualify the class name).